# SQL 7 installation guideline

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2000

My company was in the mid to migration the old application to Oracle.
Due to japan nuclear disaster, we need to set up the BCP for Japan at my country.

SQL 7 is a very old application, several thing i might not forsee.
Hope can get some guideline here.

Basically, we need to create a window 2000 virtual server to install all the old application and SQL 7.

My question is currently Japan's system are still live, we need to bring up the virtual server to be live once they activate the BCP.
Our plan is switch the new virtual server Domain name and window name with Japan's live system to make sure this was transparent to end user at Japan and everything are still on going.

Is there any concern or thing i shall take note?
When we rename the window server 2000, does SQL 7 still working?
Thanks.

Comment: With all due respect, but if this is actually critical, then the person asking the question should have better English language skills than you do. Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @John - his/her English isn't that bad, just a lot of subject/verb agreement issues.  It's pretty clear what they are asking but it still should be on serverfault.

Comment: @JNK: it's clear enough for normal use, but this looks urgent, and it looks like it matters how quickly an accurate answer is given. In that case, I recommend that the language gap be closed.

Comment: I think that the bigger issue is that someone is asking a question this critical here instead of hiring a consultant.

Comment: I'm no expert in SQL, but I thought that it doesn't take kindly to having the hostname changed out from under it.  Make sure you're taking all that into account.  And you probably want to get a live consultant.

Answer (score 3):

Before you install your new database be sure to BACKUP your database files, switching over should not be too hard, but losing your data over a mucked up memory stick is NOT irreversible, simple to do and point out I know, but it is simple to and not realise until after it is irreversible!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these same steps apply to SQL Server 7.0 (the small amount of documentation I can find says it works the same way, and it's pretty similar to SQL Server 2000, where these steps work, so I think it's likely), but after renaming the computer hosting SQL Server, you should do the following in Query Analyzer:

```
sp_dropserver <old_name>
GO
sp_addserver <new_name>, local
GO
```

Then restart SQL Server.

Comment: yes, this step work. but before that we need to restore the master db to make sure all the login and setting are still maintain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I did manage to get it done and solve the issue.

I did migrate all the db include the default master database and rename the db server.
lastly setup the replication.

So that the BCP can execute at anytime without any lost data.